# Why is the order of an ideal with respect to a prime ideal well defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

[image]

This is the definition of $\text{ord}_P A$ in Ireland and Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory". $D$ is the ring of algebraic integers of some algebraic number field and ideals are assumed to be nonzero.

Why does the paragraph above the definition justify it?

Comment: What do you mean by "well-defined" in this case? Are you asking why $t$ is unique?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am asking why there is such $t$

Comment: You also need the fact that $\bigcap_{n} P^n = \{0\}$.

Comment: Is $D$ the ring in which all these ideals are considered?

Comment: @Claudius So it doesn’t follow from the earlier paragraph?

Comment: @Adayah  All ideals are in D

Comment: Please do *not* try to learn algebraic number theory from I&R.  That book has great accounts of other material, but its chapter on algebraic number theory is simply too terse to really grok what is going on without reading an actual book on algebraic number theory first.  The number ${\rm ord}_P(A)$ is the highest power of $P$ in the prime ideal factorization of $A$, so asking why it's well defined is like asking why each prime number has a highest power dividing a positive integer.

Comment: @KCd Don't we need uniqueness of prime factorization to say that? The book shows uniqueness using $\text{ord}_P$.

Comment: Uniqueness of prime ideal factorization can be proved without using the ${\rm ord}_P$ functions.  Usually the ${\rm ord}_P$ functions are introduced after unique prime ideal factorization is established.